# Swapping ReactJS functional component on state change

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-functional-component

I am new to react and struggling to change the state of a component, and on the change replace the contents.

I have the following:

```js
function App() {

 const [page, setPage] = React.useState('list');

 switch(page) {
  case 'A':
   return(
   <body> 
    <Home />
    <A />
   </body>
  )
  case 'B':
  return(
   <body> 
    <Home />
    <B />
   </body>
  )
 }
}

function A() {
 
 return (
  <div>
   <div onClick={() => setPage('B')}>GoToB</div>
  </div>
 )
}

function B() {
    return (
       <div>test</div>
    )
}
```

There is a separate `Home` component that displays properly. How do I correctly call the `setPage` function to change the state so that the switch case is triggered and changes out the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function App() {

 const [page, setPage] = React.useState('list');

function A({setPage}) {
 
 return (
  <div>
   <div onClick={() => setPage('compsci')}>GoToB</div>
  </div>
 )
}

function B({setPage}) {
    return (
      <div>
   <div onClick={() => setPage('list')}>GoToB</div>
  </div>
    )
}

 switch(page) {
  case 'list':
   return(
   <body> 
    <Home />
    <A setPage={setPage}/>
   </body>
  )
  case 'compsci':
  return(
   <body> 
    <Home />
    <B setPage={setPage} />
   </body>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea of this worked but instead of saying `setPage={setPage}` I had to use `callback={setPage}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hook built for it his name is useEffect.

[useEffect Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

It's saying when a state change does "function".